# ORA-01427 - CONNECT BY PRIOR

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query:

```
SELECT     eo.mch_code, eo.mch_name, eo.serial_no, eo.category_id,
       eo.sup_mch_code, eo.GROUP_ID, eo.cost_center,
       (SELECT     e1.sup_mch_code
              FROM equipment_object e1
             WHERE e1.sup_mch_code LIKE 'OBIEKT-S/%'
        CONNECT BY PRIOR e1.sup_mch_code = e1.mch_code
        START WITH e1.mch_code = eo.mch_code) obiekt_s_kod,
       (SELECT e2.mch_name
          FROM equipment_all_object e2
         WHERE e2.mch_code =
                  (SELECT     e1.sup_mch_code
                         FROM equipment_object e1
                        WHERE e1.sup_mch_code LIKE
                                              'OBIEKT-S/%'
                   CONNECT BY PRIOR e1.sup_mch_code =
                                               e1.mch_code
                   START WITH e1.mch_code = eo.mch_code)) obiekt_s_nazwa
  FROM equipment_object eo
 WHERE eo.contract LIKE NVL (UPPER ('&umiejscowienie'), '%')
   AND eo.mch_code LIKE NVL (UPPER ('&obiekt_podrzedny'), '%')
   AND NVL (eo.cost_center, ' ') LIKE NVL (UPPER ('&MPK'), '%')
CONNECT BY PRIOR eo.mch_code = eo.sup_mch_code
START WITH eo.sup_mch_code LIKE UPPER ('&obiekt_nadrzedny')
```

but when I compile this query I got error:

```
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
```

where is a mistake ?? I read a lot of topics but I dont search my problem

Comment: Cześć Przemek! You put subqueries on a list of columns to select. It is OK as a general idea, but such a subquery must return a single value (and thus only one row), so using "connect by" clause in that subquery is inappropriate. What result do you want to get?

Comment: From what I see, you want to concatenate the `mch_name` column from for all the parents, like `'parent1\parent2\parent3'`. If you want that, you can use the `LISTAGG` function (if you are using Oracle 11g) in the `SELECT` statement of the subqueries.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I resolve this problem :) !

I must insert condition : rownum =1

example like this:

```
    SELECT     eo.mch_code, eo.mch_name, eo.serial_no, eo.category_id,
       eo.sup_mch_code, eo.GROUP_ID, eo.cost_center,
       (SELECT     e1.sup_mch_code
              FROM equipment_object e1
             WHERE e1.sup_mch_code LIKE 'OBIEKT-S/%'
             and rownum=1
        CONNECT BY PRIOR e1.sup_mch_code = e1.mch_code
        START WITH e1.mch_code = eo.mch_code) obiekt_s_kod,
       (SELECT e2.mch_name
          FROM equipment_all_object e2
         WHERE e2.mch_code =
                  (SELECT     e1.sup_mch_code
                         FROM equipment_object e1
                        WHERE e1.sup_mch_code LIKE
                                              'OBIEKT-S/%'
                                              and rownum=1
                   CONNECT BY PRIOR e1.sup_mch_code =
                                               e1.mch_code
                   START WITH e1.mch_code = eo.mch_code)) obiekt_s_nazwa
  FROM equipment_object eo
 WHERE eo.contract LIKE NVL (UPPER ('&umiejscowienie'), '%')
   AND eo.mch_code LIKE NVL (UPPER ('&obiekt_podrzedny'), '%')
   AND NVL (eo.cost_center, ' ') LIKE NVL (UPPER ('&MPK'), '%')
CONNECT BY PRIOR eo.mch_code = eo.sup_mch_code START WITH eo.sup_mch_code LIKE UPPER ('&obiekt_nadrzedny')
```

Comment: This way the "connect by" clause seems redundant in the subqueries. You probably can remove it and replace "start with" with "and".

Comment: If I replace "start with" with "and" it doesnt good because I dont get results(is empty) I think "rownum=1" is not the best  solution but it works :)